# Is it possible to create a Blazor Server Multi-tenant app that authenticates with microsoft Identity?

Tags: blazor, multi-tenant

I have created a Blazor Server side app that requires multi tenant authentication.  I have added a clientId column to the data tables, that will be used for data separation between clients (tenants).
I dont want to create my own login and authentication provider, as I'm worried it wont be secure.  However, I cant see any way to get the user Id after login,  so I have no idea how to get a users ClientId. I could use the Identity.name property,  but that is no good if there are users with duplicate names.
Do I need to create custom login / user registration?

Comment: Might be easier to use one of the multi-tenant libraries. [Finbuckle](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant) is one, but there are others and each have their strengths and weakness.

Comment: I think your looking for a claim called "oid" by memory.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Identity, when you upload all the users from the multi-tenant, they will have attached the proper userID(which is unique) in the data table, so using the **UserManager** you can use methods like **FindByIdAsync** or **FindByEmailAsync** but here you could have a problem, if you charge individual users to the data table, and you have any duplicate client in the tenants (which is the case you are specifying), you will have a problem that you doesn't know in which tenant is the client, assuming that in your login request you will have **[AspNetUserLogins]** table with the login provider and the proper key attached with this, so your best solution is **FindByLoginAsync**.

Once the user login into your system, you could ask to the database the userId with findByLoginAsync, and with that user, you could simply get the clientId with **user.ClientId**

Comment: If email is used as the username, there should not be duplicates -   at least I can enforce that..   In this instance, a user should not be a member of more than one client.      So, I think I can create a relationship to Client by adding an entry to a ClientUsers table  when the user is created.    Then, just lookup the user on the ClientUsers table to get the client, and do all filtering on this ClientID

Comment: That's right, but i saw in one multi-tenant project duplicate emails (in which i use aspNetUserLogins to identify the proper one). But in case that there is no duplicate like you say, you could create a relationship easy, you will find the reference of the client id looking for the user via email

Comment: I have managed to configure Identity to use a custom table (Employees), rather than AspNetUsers -  it had all the user info already. But, I had to add the columns from AspNetUsers onto it.    Then, I replaced all instances of IdentityUser with 'Employee'.     I also had to change the Id column to nvarchar(450) .   Then, I edited the DBContext to add the new columns into Employee   .           and now I have it working. just need to pass client to the db context. and add entity.HasQueryFilter(e => e.Client == clientId);  to each entity.

Comment: Great,  if you need help at least to discuss about identity, let me know